# iPhone/Objective-C - UIDocumentInteractionController Class Reference when presenting a view and delegates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage, uidocumentinteraction

I am using `UIDocumentInteractionController` inside my application in order to present the Instagram filter screen as described here from within my application:

http://instagram.com/developer/iphone-hooks/

**[UIDocumentInteractionController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation:**

I'm not quite sure whether it's possible to dismiss the Instagram filter screen and return back to my application with the modified `UIImage` after it has been uploaded (or maybe after it's been filtered) by Instagram.

As far as I know I don't think this is possible, as there's no delegate method that's available once an application has been spawned and this would most-likely involve a dismiss button from within the Instagram filter screen.

Either way, I'd also like to know whether there's a suitable way to at least return the URL/ID from Instagram once it's been posted so that I can reference the modified image from inside my application using either their API documentation or by just referencing the image url.

Thanks in advance and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding from reading the material you provided is that using UIDocumentInteractionController to do this actually *opens* Instagram and switches to it. If that's true, then the only way to receive a callback or any kind of information from Instagram would be if they supported it explicitly. I encourage you to ask them by email (contact@instagr.am) or on the Google group (perhaps [you already did?](http://groups.google.com/group/instagram-api-developers/browse_thread/thread/9b1e5e7974325ee5)).

(If they did support it, I'd imagine you might be able to call up Instagram with a URL like `instagram://[regular options]?callback=myapp://callback_url`, which they would then open when finished.)

Comment: I have sent them a support email Awaiting their response, I also reminded them of that Google group question. Haven't heard a response as of yet.